Efficiently Calculate Permutations Of A Column In A Dask Array
I have a dask array of data that also has spatial coordinates in it. I would like to calculate spatial statistics on my data (specifically Moran's I) and I would also like to calculate a P-Value for it. To calculate P-Values I will need to randomise the data and recalculate Moran's I every time.
Here is a toy example of my data
import numpy as np

coords = np.random.random((1000, 3))
coords[:, 2] = coords[:, 0] + np.random.normal(0, 0.1, 1000)
coords = np.clip(coords, 0, 1)

import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

data = dd.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(coords, columns=['x', 'y', 'v']), npartitions=10)

This looks like this:

And if I compute the dataframe it looks like this:
data_c = data.compute()
data_c


My desired output would look like this:
for i in range(5):
    data_c[f'v_perm_{i}'] = np.random.permutation(data_c['v'])
data_c


But I would like to be able to do this without computing the dataframe and in a timely/computationally efficient manner. I understand that what I am asking may be an impossible task. I know that I can shuffle within partitions but I do not believe that these repartitions would be statistically valid for calculating P-Values.
Pointers to any other packages or literature would also be appreciated.
===== EDIT/ADDITION =====
Failing being able to permute the whole data set, is it possible to repartition the data such that (1) each partition is roughly equally sized and (2) contains a spread of spatial points (x and y).
